# How could somebody who controls lemons defeat the worlds militaries

Tags: warfare, super-powers, military

In my story I have a character that
has the ability to control citrus fruits and their properties. This character has to be able to overthrow a country.

Applications of this characters powers include

-Controlling the amount of acid in a lemon for lethal effects.

-Creating up to 200 lemons in a minute.

-Manipulation of lemons in an extremely large area up to 15 kilometers.

-Manipulation of lemons inside the human body.

-Making lemons seem much more appealing and tasty to eat.

-Instantly converting any fruit to lemonade via magic.

-When lemons are converted into lemonade the lemonades properties can be controlled to lethal effect.

-Shooting out the lemonade akin to what choso from jujutsu kaisen does with blood.

- Lastly, this character can instantly explode anybody who says the phrase, “When life gives you lemons make lemonade”

So how can this character take over a country and defeat this countries military? Also, assume this country has a military on the level of a nuclear power.

Comment: `"Similarly asking for techniques or strategies can be on topic (if insufficiently constrained close as too broad)."`              `"Capabilities of characters within a world and creation of groups of characters (like nations) are on-topic, but questions must focus on what is possible or likely to develop, not what someone would or should do."` Why is this question off topic?

Comment: Given that OP is asking what someone would or should do, it should be obvious based on what you’ve quoted why it was closed.

Comment: @sphennings that's a strange comment to write when the OP is clearly asking what their character _could_ do in order to achieve a certain objective. I.e they are asking after strategy.

Comment: @MS --- If the OP wants strategy, then she can ask about strategy. This is literally a list of powers followed by "which of these should I pick?" I can easily see how it could be interpreted as story based: "which of these should my character pick?" While the underlying scenario is mildly amusing, the question needs a lot of work.

Comment: @MS Given that the most prominent text of the post is "How could somebody who controls lemons defeat the worlds militaries" do you think it's meaningful to split hairs about the difference between could and would or should? Seems like they want a way for their character to solve an in world problem. How they do this does not establish or clarify any facts about the world.

Comment: @elemtilas the OP never asks anything even resembling "which of these should I pick?". They describe the powerset, they describe the objective, and they ask how that objective could be achieved given the powerset.

Comment: @sphennings given that the difference between, would, could, and should is _literally_ how the difference between story-based and non-story-based questions is defined in meta, I fail to see how it's splitting hairs. The fact that you've now shifted the goalposts of your argument and are using your own headcanon as to what posts are allowed makes it clear you don't intend to argue in good faith.

Comment: @sphennings Here's a quote directly from the help center, describing what kind of posts are allowed: `Events: Questions need to include the setting/situation and the event or, the result you are trying to get to and the setting/situation.`

Comment: @MS --- List of powers. "How can my character do X?" It's totally opinion based and story based. There's no "rules of the world / scenario" problem to be solved here. Case in point: o.m.'s answer.  O.M. literally picked three random things from the list and plopped them in an answer.

Comment: @elemtilas I'm sorry but by that logic every question that isn't purely based on hard science and maths is opinion based and should therefore be closed

Comment: @MS --- No need to apologise MS! I agree with you: the vast majority of our questions are, *by definition* opinion based! It's been a constant wonder that WB.SE even exists on the SE network for that very reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously in a rather silly setting. But the powers can be combined ...

1. Turn any fruit in the military barracks into lemons (power #6).
2. Make the soldiers eat the lemons (power #5).
3. Threaten to manipulate the lemons in the stomach (power #4) to give their acid lethal concentrations (power #1).

With that, demand that the armed forces surrender.

Comment: Or eliminate the vitamin C and they get scurvy…